# Can I access not premultiply color from renderer's shader

Tags: javascript, glsl, pixi.js

I'm using pixi.js ver 4.8.2. 
I want access not premultiply color from renderer's shader in pixi.js application.

I set transparent is 'notMultiplied' , but I can olny access premultipilied rgb color...

Is there way to access not multiplied color ?

I want to use texture for GPGPU, so I want to access raw RGBA of texture.

I put code and result here.

```js
// init with not multiply mode
    var app = new PIXI.Application(800, 600, {
      backgroundColor : 0xcccccc,
      transparent: 'notMultiplied'
    });
    document.body.appendChild(app.view);

    // draw circle graphics with red and alpha 0.5 ( drawn at display left )
    var graphic = new PIXI.Graphics();
    graphic.alpha = 0.5;
    graphic.beginFill(0xff0000);
    graphic.drawCircle(100,100,100);
    graphic.endFill();
    app.stage.addChild(graphic);

    // use graphics as a texture ( drawn at display right )
    var mesh = new PIXI.mesh.Mesh( graphic.generateCanvasTexture() );
    mesh.position.set(300,100);
    app.stage.addChild(mesh);

    // replace MeshRenderer shader for test premultiply effect
    app.renderer.plugins.mesh.shader = new PIXI.Shader(
      app.renderer.gl,
      // vertex shader is same as original MeshRender's one
      ` 
          attribute vec2 aVertexPosition;
          attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

          uniform mat3 projectionMatrix;
          uniform mat3 translationMatrix;
          uniform mat3 uTransform;

          varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

          void main(void) {
              gl_Position = vec4((projectionMatrix * translationMatrix * vec3(aVertexPosition, 1.0)).xy, 0.0, 1.0);
              vTextureCoord = (uTransform * vec3(aTextureCoord, 1.0)).xy;
          }
      `,

      // I changed change fragment shader for test
      `
          varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
          uniform vec4 uColor;
          uniform sampler2D uSampler;

          void main(void) {
              //gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord) * uColor; <- remove
              gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord).rgb, 1.0); 
          }
      `
    );

    // render graphics and mesh.
    app.render();
```

```html
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.2/pixi.js"></script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

The execution result

[image]

Ideal result is like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not caused by premultiplied alpha, as you thought.
The issue is cause by the opacity attribute [`.alpha`](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html#alpha) which you have set.

```
graphic.alpha = 0.5;
```

This attribute is applied (multiplied) to all color channels and the alpha channel of the object.

If you don't want that this attributes effect the red green and blue color channels, then you have to divide the RGB channels by the opacity [`.alpha`](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html#alpha) in the fragment shader:

```
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform vec4      uColor;
uniform float     uAlpha;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main(void) {
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
    gl_FragColor  = vec4(texColor.rgb / uAlpha, 1.0); 
}
```

See the example:

```js
var app = new PIXI.Application(800, 600, {
  backgroundColor : 0xcccccc,
  transparent: 'notMultiplied',
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

var graphic = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphic.alpha = 0.5;
graphic.beginFill(0xff0000);
graphic.drawCircle(100,100,100);
graphic.endFill();
app.stage.addChild(graphic);

var mesh = new PIXI.mesh.Mesh( graphic.generateCanvasTexture() );
mesh.position.set(300,100);
app.stage.addChild(mesh);
app.renderer.plugins.mesh.shader = new PIXI.Shader(
  app.renderer.gl,
  ` 
    attribute vec2 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat3 projectionMatrix;
    uniform mat3 translationMatrix;
    uniform mat3 uTransform;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position   = vec4((projectionMatrix * translationMatrix * vec3(aVertexPosition, 1.0)).xy, 0.0, 1.0);
        vTextureCoord = (uTransform * vec3(aTextureCoord, 1.0)).xy;
    }
  `,
  `
    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    
    uniform vec4      uColor;
    uniform float     uAlpha;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler;

    void main(void) {
        vec4 texColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
        gl_FragColor  = vec4(texColor.rgb / uAlpha, 1.0); 
    }
  `
);
app.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.2/pixi.min.js"></script>
```